# Re-rendering on key-value pair object components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, key-value

I want to avoid re-render of my child component `<ChildComponent/>` whenever I update my state using a onClick in `<ChildComponent/>`.
I have my callback function in `<ParentComponent/>` which updates one of the values for the key-value pair object.

In the parent component

```
const _keyValueObject = useMemo(() => utilityFunction(array, object), [array, object])

const [keyValueObject, setKeyValueObject] = useState<SomeTransport>(_keyValueObject)

const handleStateChange = useCallback((id: number) => {
        setKeyValueObject(keyValueObject => {
            const temp = { ... keyValueObject }
            keyValueObject[id].isChecked = ! keyValueObject[id].isChecked
            return temp
        })
  }, [])

return( 
    <Container>
          {!! keyValueObject &&
               Object.values(keyValueObject).map(value => (
                   <ValueItem
                      key={value.id}
                      category={value}
                      handleStateChange ={handleStateChange}
                    />
               ))}
      </Container>
)
```

In child component `ValueItem`

```
   const clickHandler = useCallback(
        event => {
            event.preventDefault()
            event.stopPropagation()
            handleStateChange(value.id)
        },
        [handleStateChange, value.id],
    )

return (
        <Container>
            <CheckBox checked={value.isChecked} onClick={clickHandler}>
                {value.isChecked && <Icon as={CheckboxCheckedIcon as AnyStyledComponent} />}
            </CheckBox>
            <CategoryItem key={value.id}>{value.title}</CategoryItem>
        </Container>
    )
    
export default ValueItem
```

In child component if I use export default memo(ValueItem), then the checkbox does not get updated on the click.

What I need now is to not re-render every child component, but keeping in mind that the checkbox works. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are updating parent component to make sure your child component gets updated, since you map over `keyValueObject`. So if your child doesn't re-render it won't reflect the updates, what is the point of having the child component?

Comment: @SinanYaman I want to re-render only those child components in which the value changes for `value.isChecked`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spreading (`const temp = { ... keyValueObject }`) doesn't deep clone the object as you might think. So while `keyValueObject` will have a new reference, it's object values will not be cloned, so will have the same reference, so `memo` will think nothing changes when comparing the `category` prop.

**Solution:** make sure you create a new value for the `keyValueObject`'s id which you want to update. Example: `setKeyValueObject(keyValueObject => ({...keyValueObject, [id]: {...keyValueObject[id], isChecked: !keyValueObject[id].isChecked}))`. Now `keyValueObject[id]` is a new object/reference, so `memo` will see that and render your component. It will not render the other children since their references stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

## [`Working Codesandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-golick-t375b?file=/src/App.js)

#### Explanation

What you need to do is wrap the child with `React.memo`. This way you ensure that Child is memoized and doesn't re-render unnecessarily. However, that is not enough.

In parent, `handleStateChange` is getting a new reference on every render, therefore it makes the parent render. If the parent renders, all the children will re-render. Wrapping the `handleStateChange` with `useCallback` makes sure react component remembers the reference to the function. And `memo` remembers the result for `Child`.

#### [Useful resource](https://alexsidorenko.com/blog/react-list-rerender/)

Comment: I was already using the useCallback function.
Although after looking at the sandbox code, I have figured the bug, I was updating the reference of every object inside the `keyValueObject`. I was accessing the `keyValueObject[id].isChecked` directly.

Comment: No the issue was not using `memo`

Comment: `setKeyValueObject(keyValueObject => {
            return Object.values(keyValueObject).map(object => {
                return object.id === id
                    ? { ...object, isChecked: !object.isChecked }
                    : object
            })
        })`
this in handleStateChange solved it.
and yes using memo is also necessary. But I was already doing it before and it did not work.

Comment: You were not using the best practice while updating, and I fixed in it my code sandbox. But what made component re-render only on their value change was the `memo` wrap. You're welcome.

Comment: New reference will only be created if `object.id === id`

Comment: Yes, Sinan you are right, thank you for the help, I apologise if I sounded ungrateful in my previous comments.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.